# Make video keep aspect ratio in hero next to a text block

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I got a hero with two columns. One has text, other has a video embed from youtube with an iframe. The video should always keep it's ratio and dictate the text block size. Not gone lie I thought this would be easy peazy but... Any ideas on how to solve it? Can it be done? I'm going down to IE11.

Also at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/batcave/cayn8evm/6/) (included as video won't play)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.hero {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.hero__content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: deeppink;
}

.hero__media {
  flex: 1;
  flex-grow: 2;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.video-embed {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
  max-width: 950px;
  width: 100%;
}

.video-embed iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="hero__content">
    <h2>This is a awesome movie!</h2>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos excepturi molestiae rerum commodi animi, qui vel esse hic facilis facere!
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="hero__media video-embed">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/ue80QwXMRHg?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.hero {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color: deeppink;
}

.hero__content {
  flex: 1 0 150px;
}

.hero__media {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.video-embed {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
  max-width: 950px;
  width: 100%;
}

.video-embed iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="hero__content">
    <h2>This is a awesome movie!</h2>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos excepturi molestiae rerum commodi animi, qui vel esse hic facilis facere!
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="hero__media video-embed">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/ue80QwXMRHg?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</section>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k_sav/czwtLsem/)